# HttpWebRequest to pretend like a browser request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I have some code (in a Winform app) that reads [this URL](http://www.pbs.gov.au/pbs/home) using `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`.

For some reason, it recently starts returning **500** Internal Error when requested from my app.
(The response contains some HTML for the navigations, but doesn't have the main content I need)

On Firefox/Chrome/IE, it is still returning **200** OK.

The problem is I don't have control over their code, I don't know what it does on the backend that causes it to break when requested from my app.

Is there a way I can "pretend" to make the request from, say, Google Chrome? (just to avoid the error)

Comment: Just look at your request in browser (in console FireFox, for example) or use Fiddler, and copy http-message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [HttpWebRequest.UserAgent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to the value of a real browser's user agent.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");

webRequest.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36";
```